# Applying git patches from one repo to another similar structured repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, format-patch

We have 2 projects, one in rails 2.3.14 and one in rails 3.2.9, we moved the files and changed the structure a bit manually when creating the 3.2.9 repository and now, a few weeks later i want to add all the original repo missing commits to the new repo.

Tried using *git format-patch* to do it, but since we changed the structure a bit in the new project none of the patches actually applies and returns an error.

Is there a way to do it rather than manually?

Answer (score 0):

try to apply it in the new repo at a revision BEFORE you changed the structure. then merge the new branch into master

Answer (score 0):

Eventually we came to the inevitable conclusion that we have no other option but to merge those changes manually - we exported a patch list from the commits diff and merged the manually one by one, applying the changes in the right places.

Tip for the rest of you: merge frequently if you ever do something like this. applying 533 patches is not a fun thing to do.